# How to send label error on on php using jquery validator

Tags: php

I'm trying to send a label error to my input, but I got some apache error. Here is my code:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> $('#Username').after('<p class="label"> Username already exist.</p>')</script>';
```

Edit : Parse error: syntax error,  unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in c://..... On Line 68
Thats the error, thanks

Comment: Looking at the code you posted it looks have you have nested/unescaped single quotes. However, you do need to post the error message you are getting too, as we cannot speculate without information on the actual error.

Comment: Done updating the error please read edit, thanks.

Comment: Instead of echoing HTML, you can close PHP tag `?>` just before this HTML and write JS code as is. You can again open PHP tag `<?php` after this HTML script. This way, you don't have to fight hard with escaping.

Comment: I didn't know thats possible, Im afraid because its a long if else php statement. Will try it. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> $(\'#Username\').after(\'<p class="label"> Username already exist.</p>\')</script>';
```

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot.